# Getting 404 for static assets in vue cli project

Tags: laravel, nginx, vue.js

I am finding it hard to deploy a project with vue webpack template. We are serving a Laravel app with nginx in our server. So opening `www.example.com` serves our laravel installation. Now I wanted to use `www.example.com/lite` to serve the lite version of the app which is an SPA build with `vue-webpack` template. And for that I created a location block in our nginx configuration

```
location /lite {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                index  index.html index.htm;
                alias /var/www/html/crm-lite/dist;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
```

And I have changed `assetsPublicPath` to `assetsPublicPath: '/lite'` in `build/index.js`; But when I open it on browse I am getting 404 not found for the static assets. The url looks like this `http://example.com/lite/static/js/app.3c11ea8ceff19f8f33ff.js`

If i copy the contents of the `dist/` folder into our document root and open it with only ip address it works fine. Is there any configuaration i am missing? Thanks for help.

Comment: I am guessing that you have a conflicting `location` block for URIs ending with `.js`. Try using: `location ^~ /lite { ... }` instead.

Answer (score 1):

alias is not a terribly reliable method for moving a page, I've found; but it does offer the unique ability to redirect static requests to another folder outside of the parent, which is nice.

I played with your config for a bit before I figured out what was going on: you missed the trailing / in the directory path. (PS, you don't need the try_files or index directives)

Try this:

```
location /lite {
    alias /var/www/html/crm-lite/dist/;
}
```